# How can i know the actual geographical location of a database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dictionary, gis

I am tasked to get the location where our SQL Server database is geographically located via C# code because it may vary time to time due to frequent relocation of our database to protect it from physical and cyber harm. Is this possible or another dream of my boss thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716748/c-reverse-ip-domain-check

Comment: I gotta ask -- why? Why is the physical location of the database important?

Comment: I gotta wonder why the database is moved around so frequently?... unless you're doing something illegal.. it's going to be much safer to just put the server in a secure server room... because you're probably going to not protect it from cyber harm if you end up identifying the server by dns address or another similar publicly facing call. More than that, the actual act of relocating your server time and time again is likely to be a much more weak point than having your server in a reliable and secure location.

Comment: its not illegal it's for a good cause ;)

Comment: I might have answered prematurely but could you clarify if its Azure your using to host your dB? or is it another cloud provider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - [Buy somethihng like this.](http://www.amazon.com/USGlobalSat-BU-353-WaterProof-Enabled-Receiver/dp/tech-data/B000V5TV22/ref=de_a_smtd)  It's a UPS GPS receiver.

2 - Connect it to the server machine.

3 - Write a batch or shell script that will call the GPS software and return the current position.

4 - Use `xp_cmdshell` to call this script and return the current position via SQL Server query.

Comment: +1 that device is cool, but like my suggestion of a CLS Sproc xp_cmdshell won't fly on azure (but the OP hasn't clarified its azure)

Comment: - but if he could plug a USB device in then its not cloud

Comment: @JeremyThompson - yeah, it's not clear if it's cloud or not.  If it is obviously this won't really work.

Answer (score 6):

Buy an iPhone/Android phone and have it sellotaped to the top of the machine that has the database on it.  Write a quick app to have it look at the GPS API and post it's position to the database the phone is connected on using some kind of JSON/SOAP API over HTTPS (for security purposes).

You can then access the GPS information from where you are using C#.

**Edit**

Working with the GPS on Mono/iPhone: http://drdobbs.com/mobility/222600599

Example code, GPS on Mono/Android: https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/LocationDemo/LocationActivity.cs

Comment: But can i use this to make a response from the database of his current location?

Comment: Well this could be more accurate but what if datacenter is well isolated and phones have no signal? also requires plenty of hardware to buy...

Comment: @DavidePiras I probably should have noted it wasn't a serious answer, though it's entirely feasible.  But, why so much hardware to buy?  It's just an Android phone... You could hypothetically write the app in Mono C#.  The database server already exists.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I see that this is a good idea, but is there any get aways here by simple use of plain text and code?

Comment: Although tongue in cheek, this is worthy of consideration. You want location? Use GPS. IP isn't reliable.

Comment: @gbn can you give me idea how to use that GPS?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to do a DNS lookup, then use an IP location service as Cody suggested.  Try this:

```
var foo = Dns.GetHostEntry("database.windows.net");
```

Once you've got your IP address, you'll need to load something like  http://www.iplocationfinder.com/65.55.23.107 using an HttpWebRequest, unless you want to pay for an IP location database.  Once you've got the response to the HttpWebRequest, you can use a regular expression to parse the location name, or latitude and longitude if you need that instead.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have so many servers which are moved around overnight in your company or is this for a cloud db setup? the IP address is probably a basic inaccurate-better than nothing starting point.

Answer (score 2):

As Davide Piras mentioned you can use for example this site : http://ip-lookup.net/ to trace the IP Address of you're DB Server and you can grab the Output maybe using Regular Expresion's or http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ .

Bu that works only if you can get you're DB Server IP Address ,which i think shouldn't be an Issue because you need the IP for the Connection String .

To achieve that use a WebBrowser Control ,do `webbrowser1.navigate("http://ip-lookup.net/");` 
than :

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("text") && el.GetAttribute("name").Equals("ip"))
                {
                    el.InnerText = "Server IP";
                }
            }
```

next :

```
HtmlElement form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("form_single_IP");
            if (form != null)
                form.InvokeMember("submit");
             //Submit the form
```

and try to filter the output because im not very good using Regex .You can capture the Output by using `webbrowser1.DocumentText;`

Comment: But this one is for me? not for the server where the database is located right?

Comment: @AllanChua No you need to get the Database Server IP Address and using this type of Web Site(Services) you can find the Geographic Location of the DataBase server(not so precise but it work's)

Comment: can you give me a way how to do that when all you have is connection string to the database that has an alias?

Comment: @AllanChua i`ll Update my question

Comment: This is a sample connection string of azure clients jd39urj4j4.database.windows.net

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the database to tell you the location? To clarify what I mean:

[Using SQL CLR Stored Procedure To Track IP Address](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/2010/04/24/Using-SQL-CLR-Stored-Procedure-Track-IP-Address.aspx) - but make the CLR sproc return the ipaddress of the server its hosted on.

I saw the azure connection string you mentioned to Cody and thought these would be a handy links:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/06/windows-azure-deployments-and-the-virtual-ip-address.aspx

[Get Azure public IP address from deployed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329118/get-azure-public-ip-address-from-deployed-app)

Answer (score 1):

Determining the time zone is probably the best you can do from SQL Server, but that could be enough for you based on your description. You can use this query to get the GMT offset of the time zone where the server is located:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()) AS ServerTimeZone
```

From this result, you can easily add some logic to return the time zone abbreviation, i.e. `EST`, `CST`, etc. I know this isn't much, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Yeah.. this would also help in checking if the gps position returned by the gadgets is correct thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone already physically moves the server, why not write some script that writes the corresponding location to DB? When the machine starts up, auto-start that tool and have the "mover" select a location.